# Dom selection - selecting the second td in table row

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm doing Dom selection with `table tr td` but this gives me all td in the table. How can I choose only the second td in every row?

Comment: Always good to include the code you're using. `:)`

Comment: @sameold What library / utility is that? It's not PHP's [native DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
table tr td:nth-child(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the DOM library, try this XPath expression

```
// $doc is your DOM Document
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$cells = $xpath->query('//table/tr/td[2]');
```